# Nest JS setting up a schema with fields as nested objects

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, mongoose-schema, nest

I have such model in Mongo:

```
{
  ...
  settings: {
    positions: [
      {
       column: number,
       row: number,
       buttonId: (ref to Button model)
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In schema:

```
@Schema({ _id: false })
@ObjectType()
class Settings {
  @Field(() => [Object])
  @Prop({ type: [{ column: Number, row: Number, buttonId: String }] })
  positions: { column: number; row: number; buttonId: string };
}

const SettingsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Settings);

@Schema()
@ObjectType()
export class Keyboard {
  @Field(() => ID)
  _id: string;

  @Field(() => User)
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  author: User;

  @Field(() => Group, { nullable: true })
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' })
  group?: Group;

  @Field(() => Settings, { nullable: true })
  @Prop({ type: SettingsSchema })
  settings?: Settings;
}

export const KeyboardSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Keyboard);
```

Get this error:
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBNrD.png)]

How can i resolve it?

Need to use nested objects in my schemas with using GraphQl. @Field decorator doesn't work with nested object fields correctly

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build the positions `@ObjectType` first, then use it in `Settings` class

```
@Schema({ _id: false })
@ObjectType('Position')
class Position {
  @Field(() => Number)
  column: number

  @Field(() => Number)
  row: number
  ...
}
```

And then change your `Settings` object to

```
@Schema({ _id: false })
@ObjectType('Settings')
class Settings {
  @Field(() => [Positions])
  positions: Positions[]
}
```